# How to Generate Spring JPA Entities Given Database Model (Telosys)?

Tags: telosys

I am currently using **Telosys** to help me generate **Spring JPA Entity Classes** from an existing database. So far, I could generate the repository, service, provider directory by using **java7-persistence-spring-data-jpa** template, but not the entity. Is it possible to generate these entities if you are using the database model (not the DSL model)?

Answer (score 4):

I already figured it out. Looks like each templates serve different purposes in Telosys. If you encounter the same problem with mine, try switching it to this template: **java-jpa-entities-T330**.

You can explore more java templates here in their [github.](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3?q=java&type=&language=&sort=)

Answer (score 4):

As described at the end of this post https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/  each "bundle of templates" is designed to generate a subpart of the final application.

[image]

It's a way to manage separately the differents concerns of a project (REST controllers, domain classes, persitence, unit tests, etc)